# How do I use *ngFor to iterative twice on the same object?

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I used the Angular integrator *ngFor to iterate through an object in my HTML. Since am I iterating twice, I have a problem coming from this double iteration, where `[specID]`, an Input I bind to my TimelineComponent, is being displayed in 2 loops.

```
<div *ngFor="let pos of scenario.time">
  <div *ngFor="let spectra of scenario.getSpectra()">
    <timeline [specId]="spectra.id" [ticks]="[pos]"></timeline>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is my Scenario type (I'm not sure if this is relevant) :

```
import {spectra} from "../data";
import {Spectra} from "./spectra";

export class Scenario {
  id: string;
  time: number[];
  spectra: string[];

  constructor(id: string, time: number[],
              spectra: string[],
              ) {
    this.spectra = spectra;
    this.id = id;
    this.time = time;
  }

  getSpectra(): Spectra[] {
    return spectra.filter(spectrum => this.spectra.includes(spectrum.id))
  }
}
```

And both of my arrays, scenarios and spectra :

```
export const scenarios: Scenario[] = [
  new Scenario( "1", [0.0, 0.14, 1], ["1", "2", "3"]),
  new Scenario( "2", [0.0, 0.33, 1], ["1", "2", "3"])
];

export const spectra: Spectra[] = [
  new Spectra("1", [0.2, 0.2, 0.6], ["1", "2", "3"]),
  new Spectra("2", [0.33, 0.33, 0.33], ["1", "2", "3"]),
  new Spectra("3", [0.4, 0.4, 0.2], ["1", "2", "3"])
];
```

What is the best way to come around this problem? I tried to use both of my `*ngFor` in the same div but it seems I can't use that.

Comment: Show `scenario`

Comment: Please add more info, or share more of your code. Besides, what's the connection between `scenario.getSpectra()` and `scenario.time`?

Comment: there is no connection between them. I use ```scenario.getSpectra()``` to link scenario to the Spectra object and ```scenario.time``` is to get the time value. I'll add more code.

Comment: I would suggest processing your collections in the component or service, and handing your template collection to iterate through. If you don't, Angular is going to run scenario.getSpectra() every change detection cycle. Maybe this change alone would be enough to simplify the logic here and solve the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to prepare a combined list in your component class with of all possible combination of the two lists( `time` and `getSpectra()` ). Then use only single loop in your template.

Add the followings to your component class

```
export class SomeComp implements OnInit {
    ...
    someList: any[];
    ...
    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.someList = [];
        for(let t of this.scenario.time)
            for(let s of this.scenario.getSpectra())
                this.someList.push({pos: t, spectraId: s});
    }
    ...
}
```

And change the template like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of someList">
    <timeline [specId]="item.spectraId" [ticks]="[item.pos]"></timeline>
</div>
```

Updated example as suggested in the comment.

Comment: This is solution will perform better than the original if you use ngOnInit vs a getter on every change detection cycle.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that `scenario.time` and `scenario.getSpectra()` are related by the virtue of the position in the array.

Then you can access like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let spectra of scenario.getSpectra(); let i = index">
    <timeline [specId]="spectra.id" [ticks]="pos[i]"></timeline>
  </div>
```

Comment: you can try scenario.getSpectra()[i]

Comment: I can't really mix ```scenario.time``` and ```scenario.getSpectra()``` this way